# I am having trouble with the move-item function to move multiple files into separate folders

Tags: powershell

So the path folder contains multiple files, approx 19,000, all named "XXXX_YYY YYY" where x is any 1-4 digit number and Y is text phrases. Based on the beginning number f the file, I am trying to move the respective files into folders designated with their number.

To test out, I started to attempt to move 1 file and received the error code pictured way below.To give some insight, i didn't use an equal sign and give the path folder an alias because I will be doing this in a bulk copy and paste fashion for the 19,000 files.

Here's the code I tried.

```
Move-Item -Path D:\Data EEA1\Application Documents1\27_Assignment of Incentive Form -Destination D:\Data EEA1\Folders\27
```

Here's the error message I received.

```
Move-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'EEA1\Application'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Move-Item -Path D:\Data EEA1\Application Documents1\27_Assignment of  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Move-Item], ParameterBindingException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please format your code examples as code for better readability.

However, what's generating the error is that you have spaces in the path, which makes powershell think that you are giving it multiple parameters instead of just one long path.

The easiest way of dealing with that is to just wrap the -Path parameter in either single or double quotes:

```
Move-Item -Path "D:\Data EEA1\Application Documents1\27_Assignment of Incentive Form" -Destination D:\Data EEA1\Folders\27
```

Good standard practice is to do it with all string parameters anyway:

```
Move-Item -Path 'D:\Data EEA1\Application Documents1\27_Assignment of Incentive Form' -Destination 'D:\Data EEA1\Folders\27'
```

Comment: In addition to your solution I realized I had to include the extension (.pdf)